# Magento2 - Number of search results

Tags: magento-2.1, search, catalogsearch, indexing, search-terms

In my **Magento2** store I am only getting 9 search results visible, although there are more hits ...
But there is no pagination at the underside to go to the next page ...

So something is overruling this.

What **`XML`** file should I look for?

[image]

Because when i look for shirts, i have 190 results. But only 9 are shown (standard number of items per page)

Comment: did you try to reset and reindex?

Comment: Yes I did. But I think its being overided somewere. Because in layered attribute I can filter on size too

Comment: please share screen shot

Comment: done, screenshot is added